Why are some `Packages` files in APT repositories 0 bytes, and how does APT then choose packages from other release versions?
EDIT - INTRO:
I'm asking this question to understand the behavior of APT, which should've have changed much from back then. I'm not trying to install these old packages on my current system.

I'm aware that Gazebo Classic <11 is EOL
I'm aware that Ubuntu (LTS) < 22.04 (Focal Fossa) and Ubuntu < 23.10 (Mantic Minotaur) are EOL
I'm aware that packages packaged for one release can have dependency conflicts with packages in other releases


If you check Gazebo 3.0 installation tutorial, it says that Gazebo 3.0 can be installed on the Ubuntu Raring Ringtail release.
But if you look at dists/raring/main/binary-amd64/, the Packages file is of 0 bytes.
So it somehow falls back to using the package available in Precise Pangolin. But I can't figure out how it happens. Shouldn't we have to manually add the precise repo in Raring if we have to use it?
The command used is sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu raring main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gazebo-latest.list', so it is only looking at the raring repo.
The package gazebo3 was only packaged for Precise Pangolin and Trusty Tahr (instructions did not list it), and should definitely be using the version from Precise, because Trusty is newer.

Another Example:
According to Gazebo 2.2 installation tutorial, it says that Gazebo 2.2 can be installed on every release from Precise to Trusty.
It says Precise to Roaring should use gazebo-current and Saucy and Trusty should use gazebo2.
If you check pool/main/g/gazebo-current/, gazebo-current (v2.2.5) it is only packaged for precise and likewise, pool/main/g/gazebo2/, gazebo2 (v2.2.6) is only packaged for trusty.
So in this case, Quantal Quetzel and Raring Ringtail are falling back to Precise Pangolin, while Saucy Salamander is going forward to Trusty Tahr.
And like the previous case, the Packages file in quantal,raring and saucy are 0 bytes. This is not even about them being LTS. Yakkety Yak and Zesty Zapus have non-empty Packages files, and they list Gazebo packages which are available in pool/main/g/ too (gazebo8 for Yakkety and gazebo7 and gazebo8 for Zesty).
How does the package manager know which package to use? There doesn't even seem to be a standard format, such as fall back to previous releases. Since we are specifying the release codename and not the version number, APT should not even be able to deduce that there are older or newer releases to pull from.
The later instructions just say sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu-stable 'lsb_release -cs' main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gazebo-stable.list', so whatever the release is gets specified in sources.list.d. It would've made sense if only the releases for which it was packaged were able to install it. But that is not the case here.

So my question is, how do these 0 byte Packages files work with APT queries? How does APT choose another release when it encounters repos like these?
The dists/raring/Release file also shows that Packages is 0 bytes, so it's not an instance of a broken repository like mentioned here.

Why are you looking at an old verso of the page instead of the current one?  And gazebo 3 appears to be ancient.

@user10489 Because I want to package ROS for Void Linux, and it has only been consistently packaged for Ubuntu (and historically, Debian) in the OSRF repositories. Ubuntu would package it, but in a very random manner. So I wanted to explore which versions of Gazebo were packaged for which versions of Ubuntu by the official and OSRF repositories and found this strange behaviour. ROS is a complex project by OSRF which has 1000+ dependencies, and Gazebo is similar too. Both comes in distributions (Gazebo after the last classic version, 11), so "old versions" are simply different packages.

https://gazebosim.org/docs/latest/ros_installation

@user10489 ros_gz is a ROS package that allows Gazebo to integrate with ROS. But here, I have to package all three of them. They use the colcon build system which manages a complex dependency graph. As you can see from that page, the instructions are for installing the Ubuntu only. If you look at the build instructions for either ROS 2 or Gazebo instead, you'll see that they want you to add the OSRF APT (or DNF) repository after cloning in the 1000+ source repository chains using vcs import to install the system dependencies.

@user10489 That is because Ubuntu releases only package specific versions of Gazebo and ROS. For example, Gazebo 8: Harmonic is the latest, but only Gazebo 6: Fortress (which was Ignition 6: Fortress back then) is packaged from Bionic to Mantic. If you want Garden (supported in Focal and Jammy) or Harmonic (supported in Jammy), you have to make use of the OSRF repositories. Why couldn't Ubuntu package them? I don't know, maybe it's too complicated. But why did Ubuntu package some of them in a way that has no connection to what's officially supported? That's the question that led me here.

ROS also has its own repositories last I looked.

@user10489 My bad, I meant Gazebo is also included in the ROS repositories. Got confused since both are OSRF projects. And it turns out the ROS repos had Gazebo packaged for all those distros. I guess then they edited up the OSRF repo later for some reason.

The repositories listed are not "broken."
Those old repositories are closed, and the packages in them have been withdrawn.
Those old repositories cannot be used at all. Apt errors when attempting to use them are expected behavior.
Releases of Ubuntu before 18.04 are no longer supported, and those repositories are closed (exception: Pro/esm).
Apt does not "choose another release"; it will use only the release specified in your apt sources. It doesn't know about any other releases.

Why are only some of the repositories closed, and the others are not? The Package files are available for precise (12.04), trusty (14.04), vivid (15.04), xenial (16.04), yakkety (16.10), zesty (17.04) and artful (17.10), all of them which are behind bionic. OSR Foundation repos are (or at least seem to be) unlike Ubuntu repos where the EOL-ed versions get removed or archived.

"Those old repositories cannot be used at all. Apt errors when attempting to use them are expected behavior." "Releases of Ubuntu before 18.04 are no longer supported" -- I was not referring to using the current Ubuntu release with those repositories. I'm aware that mixing packages can cause dependency conflicts.

I think my doubt was cleared after having a look at the ROS repository. It has all the gazebo packages in the appropriate releases. The reason some releases in the OSRF repository has empty Packages list would be because they just closed them after EOL (while the others were LTS). I'll mark this as the answer, since it clears my doubt about APT choosing other releases.
